# Fixed point of quantum operations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-theory, fixed-point-theorems, quantum-computation

A quantum operation is defined as
\begin{equation}
\varepsilon(\rho)=\sum_{k}M_k\rho M_k^{\dagger}
\end{equation}
where $\varepsilon(\rho)$ takes an initial state $\rho$ to some final state $\rho'$ and $M_k^{\dagger}M_k$'s are positive, contractive operators that satisfy
\begin{equation}
\sum_kM_k^{\dagger}M_k=\mathbb{I}.
\end{equation}
It is known through Schauder's fixed point theorem that this admits a fixed point. Note that because of the summation in the first equation, it means that the measurement was not recorded.

QUESTION: If I have a single quantum measurement that was recorded, then I would only have $\varepsilon(\rho)=\frac{M_k\rho M_k^{\dagger}}{\text{tr}(M_k\rho M_k^{\dagger})}$. Would this still admit a fixed point? Is there a way to prove it?

Comment: I think you should find someone to talk to in person about this. The $M_k$ aren't assumed to be positive; the identity matrix is a fixed point (Schauder's theorem doesn't come into it), and your understanding of measurement is not correct. The terms of the sum do not represent different measurement outcomes.

Comment: As to the technical question of whether $\frac{M_k\rho M_k^\dagger}{{\rm tr}(M_k\rho M_k^\dagger)}$ must have a nonzero fixed point, the answer is no. Take $M_k = \left[\matrix{0&1\cr 0&0}\right]$ and let $\rho$ be an arbitrary $2\times 2$ matrix. (If you add the nonstandard requirement that $M_k$ be positive, then the answer is yes; let $\rho = |\lambda\rangle\langle\lambda|$ where $|\lambda\rangle$ is any nonzero eigenvector for $M_k$.)

Comment: Right. It's $M_k^{\dagger}M_k$ that is positive. What's wrong with my understanding of measurement? It's what this paper said. http://arxiv.org/abs/1110.6815 If the measurement was not recorded, it will be a sum but if it is recorded, there will be no sum. Just a single expression. The recording part is what I actually find mysterious.

Comment: "If the measurement was not recorded, it will be a sum but if it is recorded, there will be no sum." Yes, but not a term of the sum you have written. The paper you referenced looks like it has a good, thorough explanation of all this.

Comment: That's what it says on page 9. Postulates II.4 and II.5.

Comment: Okay, I see what is confusing you. You are mistaking quantum operations for POVM's. Notice on page 9 (POVM) the index is $x$ --- representing a measurement outcome --- whereas the sum in a quantum operation is $k$ --- representing a dummy index of a sum. Although they are so formally similar the confusion is completely understandable.

Comment: The most important difference is that the sum in a POVM is canonical, whereas there are typically many ways of choosing Kraus operators to express a quantum operation.

Comment: But the intuition should be completely different. A quantum operation shows how a subsystem evolves over time via a Hamiltonian that could involve interaction with some other unspecified system. A POVM describes the possible final states in a subsystem when an observable of the composite system is measured.

Comment: So when we talk of POVMs, does the fixed point concept apply? In Nielsen/Chuang's textbook, there's an exercise about the fixed point of a quantum operation. Does it make sense to ask about the fixed point of a POVM? The above question should be POVM.

Comment: Yes, I think it makes sense now. I'll put my comment in an answer.

Comment: @NikWeaver I don't see what's wrong with interpreting the different $k$ as (discarded) results of measurements. E.g., if you believe in unitarity and describe the channel through a Stinespring dilation, this is exactly the information acquired by the environment. Certainly, this way of looking at completely positive maps is very common in quantum information.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: none of the $k$'s is "discarded" in a quantum operation, so I do not understand your comment.

Comment: @NikWeaver Imagine Alice has a device which measures $M_k$ (i.e., where outcome $k$ yields a post-measurement state $\rho_k\propto M_k\rho M_k^\dagger$.  Now let's say Alice forgets the measurement outcome, or simply decides not to read it off, i.e., she discards it.  Then, the state after this procedure is $\sum M_k\rho M_k^\dagger$.  --  As I have said, it is not uncommon to think about CP maps in that way in quantum information.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch: I see what you mean now. I guess one has to be a little careful thinking about CP maps in this way, because, as I mentioned above, this kind of decomposition of a CP map is not canonical.

Comment: @NikWeaver Fair enough.  On the other hand, it also means that if we think of a CP map as being obtained by a unitary interaction with an environment, we can realize *any* measurement corresponding to a Kraus representation by measuring that environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As clarified in the comments, the question refers to positive operator valued measures, not quantum operations. Basically the issue is whether, for a given $A \in M_n = M_n(\mathbb{C})$ the map $B \mapsto ABA^*$ on $M_n$ has an eigenvector. A counterexample is given by the matrix $A = \left[\matrix{0&1\cr 0&0}\right]$; for any matrix $B = \left[\matrix{a&b\cr c&d}\right]$ we have $ABA^* = \left[\matrix{d&0\cr 0&0}\right]$, so that $0$ is the only eigenvalue.

However, if $A$ is positive then taking $B$ to be any projection onto an eigenvector of $A$ belonging to a nonzero eigenvalue yields a solution. Slightly more generally, $B$ could be any operator which satisfies $PBP = B$ where $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto some eigenspace for $A$. Putting $A$ in diagonal form shows that these are the only solutions.